# Run local executable from a remote PHP application

Tags: php, exec

in a php webapp of mine, I would need to launch the local scanner executable in order to store the scanned page in a remote folder of the webapp.

I was wondering how I can call the exe from the remote server as the exec php command runs programs on the same machine of the php.

Any clue? The aim is just to start th GUI of the scanner program, then the operator does the rest (scan, save, upload to remote folder with drag and drop html5 interface - unless you have suggestions even on this matter).

I have googled around, but honestly, i haven't fully understood the ssh2 methods, the shells and so on...

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

May be [php ftp class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) can save you. The ftp class allows to access, retrieve and manage remote host files. without using ssh.

Comment: that could solve the issue "how to programmatically store the scanned documents to a remote folder". What about running an application from remote? Any clue? Thank you for your time